# Flutter GetX controller not calling method when revisit the app screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am new to the Flutter GetX package and facing problem when using the flutter GetX package. I have several app screens where one screen for listing all the products from the database.

In my product controller, I am fetching all the data from the database and showing with listview like as given code below and It's working fine.

**Problem:** When I'm inserting a new record from another controller and come back to the product list controller it'll not showing newly added data. Actually this time `onInit` method won't fire.

**Controller code**

```
class ProductIndexCtrl extends GetxController {
    
    var products = [].obs;

    @override
    void onInit() {
     super.onInit();
     getAll();
    }

    void getAll() {
      Product.getAll().then((jsonList) {
        products.value = Product.fromJsonList(jsonList);
      });
    }
}



class ProductCreateCtrl extends GetxController {
    
     void saveData(Product product) {
        ...
        ...

        //after successful insert
        Get.toNamed('productIndex');

     }

}
```

**Product index screen**

```
final ctrl = Get.put(ProductIndexCtrl());

GetX<ProductIndexCtrl>(builder: (controller) {
    return _listview(controller.products);
}

Widget _listview(data) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the GetX dependency manager controls the lifecycle of dependencies, you should not manually call them. It's GetX's responsibility when to call them.

Therefore you need to manually call `getAll()` method of your `ProductIndexCtrl` controller inside the `saveData()` method of your `ProductCreateCtrl` like:

```
saveData(Product product){
  .... 
  ....
  final indexCtrl= Get.find<ProductIndexCtrl>();
  indexCtrl.getAll();

}
```

Comment: Damn, wasted a couple of hours but finally found the answer. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1):

By returning to that page, you can return the new information locally to the previous page

**> Controller code**

```
class ProductIndexCtrl extends GetxController {

var products = [].obs;

@override
void onInit() {
 super.onInit();
 getAll();
}

void getAll() {
  Product.getAll().then((jsonList) {
    products.value = Product.fromJsonList(jsonList);
  });
}
```

}

**> Product index screen**

```
class ProductCreateCtrl extends GetxController {

 void saveData(Product product) {
    ...
    ...

    //after successful insert
    Get.back(result: product);

 }
```

}

and get Data when back

```
Get.toName('ProductCreateCtrl').then(result){
 products.add(result);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar thing with one single controller. The code snippet is given below.

First, create the `ProductView`. Since this is the entry point of the application, So you will create a `GetX` controller inside of this.

```
/// THIS IS PARENT VIEW SO WE WILL CREATE GETX CONTROLLER HERE
class ProductView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(ProductController());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Products'),
      ),
      body: Obx(() {
        return controller.myProductList.isEmpty
            ? showNoProductView()
            : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controller.myProductList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return YourListItemView(controller.myProductList[index]);
                },
              );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

The view `AddProductView` is responsible for adding new products to the DB. We can assume that there is a `FloatingActionButton` present in `ProductView` and `onClick` on that button, we will open this `AddProductView`.

```
/// THIS IS CHILD VIEW SO WE WILL FIND THE PRODUCT CONTROLLER HERE
class AddProductView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddProductView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<ProductController>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Add Product'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // ADD YOUR OTHER WIDGETS TO GET PRODUCT INFO
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Click to Add'),
            onPressed: () {
              var productName = nameTextEditingController.text;
              var productQuantity = qtyTextEditingController.text;

              var product = YourProductObject(productName, productQuantity);
              controller.addProduct(product: product);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, the controller will look like this.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ProductController extends GetxController {
  // this will be your custom product list object
  var myProductList = <YourProductObject>[].obs;

  var dbInstance = YourDbInstance();

  @override
  void onReady() async {
    super.onReady();

    // perform database operation
    await fetchDataFromDb();
  }

  Future<void> fetchDataFromDb() async {
    // assuming that data is coming as List<YourProductListObject>
    // always use try catch in db operation. for demo purpose I am skipping that.
    var productListFromDb = await dbInstance.getYourProductListObjectList();

    myProductList.assignAll(productListFromDb);
  }

  Future<void> addProduct({required YourProductObject product}) async {
    // assuming that there is a function that returns true if a product is added to db
    var isAdded = await dbInstance.addProduct(product);

    if (isAdded) {
      myProductList.add(product);
    }
  }
}
```

Since `myProductList` is a `RxList` so getx will observe it and will update the UI accordingly. You must add `Obx((){})` in view.